# How to debug WebGL uncaught type error

Tags: webgl

I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Type error
```

When I have the WebGL Inspector enabled (in Chrome), this error originates in a file that starts with 'VM' and ends in a sequence of digits (not sure what code owns that -- is it core browser behavior or the WebGLInspector?). This is the line.

```
// Call real function
var result = originalFunction.apply(context.rawgl, arguments);
```

I enabled [the debug context](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging) and am logging all WebGL calls. This is the call that breaks:

```
uniform1i(3, 0)
```

In the WebGL inspector, I see that the uniform at index 3 is my `uniform sampler2D uSampler` in my fragment shader. The API documentation says that this is a GLint, so the type is correct. I also tried setting some other uniforms first and they also fail with the same error.

I'm reworking some existing code I wrote after following tutorials and one of the things I'm adding is interleaved vertex data. I'm sure that that is the root cause, however, this is the third time I've come across an error like this and my only recourse has been to massage the code until it goes away. It feels random and it's frustrating.

Are there any more debugging techniques? I assume it's an error in the shaders. Is there some way to get a stack trace from them?

Comment: Have you tried with any other browsers? I've found Firefox will sometimes give me more error details and on occasion IE too. There's also a new [shader editor](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/11/live-editing-webgl-shaders-with-firefox-developer-tools/) feature in FF27 but I haven't tried it yet myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uniform1i(3, 0)
```

Is not valid WebGL.  The uniform functions require a `WebGLUniformLocation` object which can only be gotten by calling `gl.getUniformLocation`

This is different from OpenGL. The reason is you are not allowed to do math on uniform locations. In OpenGL developers often make that mistake. They'll do something like this

```
--in shader--
uniform float arrayOfFloats[4];

--in code--
GLint location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "arrayOfFloats");

glUniform1f(location, 123.0f);
glUniform1f(location + 1, 456.0f);  // BAD!!!
```

That second line is not valid OpenGL but it might work depending on the driver.

In WebGL they wanted to make that type of mistake impossible because web pages need to work everywhere whereas OpenGL programs only need to work on the platform they are compiled on. To make it work everywhere they had `gl.getUniformLocation` return an object so you can't do math on the result.

The correct way to write the code above in OpenGL is

```
--in shader--
uniform float arrayOfFloats[4];

--in code--
GLint location0 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "arrayOfFloats[0]");
GLint location1 = glGetUniformLocation(program, "arrayOfFloats[1]");

glUniform1f(location0, 123.0f);
glUniform1f(location1, 456.0f);
```

And in WebGL is

```
--in shader--
uniform float arrayOfFloats[4];

--in code--
var location0 = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "arrayOfFloats[0]");
var location1 = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "arrayOfFloats[1]");

gl.uniform1f(location0, 123.0);
gl.uniform1f(location1, 456.0);
```

Comment: I'm surprised that I missed that. The spec is very clear about the type of that first argument. Thank you, gman!